# Twitter Public Stream URL when several track keywords?

Tags: python, twitter, urlencode

I'm trying to track several keywords at once, with the following url:

`https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter%2C%20whatever%2C%20streamingd%2C%20`

But the stream only returns results for the first keyword?! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without spaces (ie. the %20). Doh!